# iphone SDWebImage resize cached image

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

i am parsing json from SBJson parser and showing it in table view successfully.I am using SDWebImage to cache images for offline support by using

```
  UIImageView *thumbImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 3, 50, 50)];
        thumbImg.tag = 1;
        thumbImg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        thumbImg.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        thumbImg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        thumbImg.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
        thumbImg.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:thumbImg];

[thumbImg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myObj.thumbnailURL]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]
                        success:^(UIImage *image) {
                            NSLog(@"success");
                        }
                        failure:^(NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"write error %@", error);
                        }];
```

and its showing perfectly in my 50x50 imageview. But the thumbnail images are big in size 400x600 approx. So my tableview is scrolling very slow due to large image thumbnails loading in imageview. How can i resize the image fetched by SDWebImage before caching so that next time when it load from cache it loads small size image.I have the function to resize the image but dont know where to add that code.I tried to resize by giving the image pointer which i got in success block but it had no effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here!

This library integrates SDWebImage with a Resize library

https://github.com/toptierlabs/ImageCacheResize

Comment: Let me know if you find any errors. I will release a new version in the following days with small bug fixes

Comment: Saved me a lot of time and helped me reduce memory foot print by resizing.. Really liked the bit that changed the cache key with _bounds_...  Thanks Tony!!!

Comment: @Tony Just found a bug. When the image is read back from disk cache, the resizing is lost. After some debugging, I figured the culprit was this line in SDWebImageManager.m  `[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:image
                                          imageData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                                             forKey: cacheKey
                                             toDisk:!(options & SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly)];` Earlier, it was storing downloader.imagedata